# Chrome does not ask where to save each file before downloading

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, download

I have selected "Ask where to save each file before downloading" in Chrome, however, whenever I download a file from my email it goes directly to download and opens in Word. I don't want them there. I want to choose! I have many folders for different clients and need to compartmentalize before I open the file. I have Windows 10.

Any suggestions?

Comment: `whenever I download a file from my email` Are you using a web version of your mailbox? Does this happen when you download something directly from the web?

Answer (score 10):

I ran into this issue today where chrome was automatically downloading a text file into the downloads folder without asking where to put it even though I had the chrome setting configured to always ask for the location.  I also didn't like the idea of resetting all my settings just to try to get this to work.  This happened for some types and not others.

What I did to fix the issue in my case is the following:

1. Go to Chrome settings
2. Search for "Download"
3. At the bottom where the download options, clear option to always open in an application.  It's a third option that showed up, but once it's "cleared" doesn't show up again.

After these steps, I was immediately able to always be asked where to download files.

Comment: chrome://settings/?search=download

Comment: `Open certain file types automatically after downloading`

Comment: Happened again in 2023, the hack... I am 100% sure I've never opted-in for this.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to also need to set **Set download directory** option to **Disabled** state.

Answer (score 0):

Go to

> Settings -> Lite Mode -> Off

Lite Mode makes google chrome work faster and consumes less data.
So it doesn't allow where to save downloads option when it is on.